# calculate the sum from sub array of objects for individual object in mongoose

Tags: database, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

How to calculate the sum of **confident_score** for every individual vendor?

Data stored in the DB:

```
  [
            {
                "_id": "61cab38891152daf9387c0c7",
                "name": "dummy",
                "company_email": "abc@mailinator.com",
                "brief_msg": "Cillum sed est prae",
                "similar_case_ids": [],
                "answer_id": [
                    "61cab38891152daf9387c0c9"
                ],
                "pros_cons": [
                    {
                        "vendor_name": "xyzlab",
                        "score": [
                            {
                                "question_id": "61c5b47198b2c5bbf9f6471c",
                                "title": "Vendor F",
                                "confident_score": 80,
                                "text": "text1",
                                "_id": "61cac505caeeeb3cec78bf0f"
                            },
                            {
                                "question_id": "61c5b47198b2c5bbf9f6471c",
                                "title": "Vendor FFF",
                                "confident_score": 40,
                                "text": "text1",
                                "_id": "61cac505caeeeb3cec78bf10"
                            }
                        ]
     
                    },
                    {
                        "vendor_name": "abclab",
                        "score": [
                            {
                                "question_id": "61c5b47198b2c5bbf9f6471c",
                                "title": "Vendor B",
                                "confident_score": 50,
                                "text": "text1",
                                "_id": "61cac505caeeeb3cec78bf16"
                            },
                            {
                                "question_id": "61c5b47198b2c5bbf9f6471c",
                                "title": "Vendor BB",
                                "confident_score": 60,
                                "text": "text1",
                                "_id": "61cac505caeeeb3cec78bf17"
                            }
                        ]
                    }
                ]
```

the query for getting the matching id and grouping objects according to the vendor_name:

```
aggregate([
    {
       $match: { _id: id } 
    },
    {
      $unwind: {
           path: '$pros_cons'
         }
    },
    {  
      $group: {
         _id: '$pros_cons'
      }
    },

  ])
};
```

After query I'm getting this:

```
[
        {
            "_id": {
                "vendor_name": "abclab",
                "score": [
                    {
                        "question_id": "61c5b47198b2c5bbf9f6471c",
                        "title": "Vendor B",
                        "confident_score": 50,
                        "text": "text1",
                        "_id": "61cac505caeeeb3cec78bf16"
                    },
                    {
                        "question_id": "61c5b47198b2c5bbf9f6471c",
                        "title": "Vendor BB",
                        "confident_score": 60,
                        "text": "text1",
                        "_id": "61cac505caeeeb3cec78bf17"
                    }
                ],
            }
        },
        {
            "_id": {
                "vendor_name": "xyzlab",
                "score": [
                    {
                        "question_id": "61c5b47198b2c5bbf9f6471c",
                        "title": "Vendor F",
                        "confident_score": 80,
                        "text": "text1",
                        "_id": "61cac505caeeeb3cec78bf0f"
                    },
                    {
                        "question_id": "61c5b47198b2c5bbf9f6471c",
                        "title": "Vendor FFF",
                        "confident_score": 40,
                        "text": "text1",
                        "_id": "61cac505caeeeb3cec78bf10"
                    }
                ],
            }
        }
    ]
```

Need to calculate sum for (vendor_name:abclab)TOTAL=110 and for (vendor_name:xyzlab)TOTAL=120 INDIVIDUALLY

**required output:**

```
[
           {
                "vendor_name": "abclab",
                 "totalScore": 110,
                 "count"     : 2
           },
          {
                 "vendor_name": "xyzlab",
                 "totalScore": 120,
                 "count"     : 2

        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. `$match` - Filter documents by `id`.
2. `$unwind` - Deconstruct `pros_cons` array to multiple documents.
3. `$project` - Decorate output documents. With `$reduce`, to create `totalScore` field by summing `confident_score` from each element in `pros_cons.score` array.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      _id: "61cab38891152daf9387c0c7"
    }
  },
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$pros_cons"
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      _id: 0,
      vendor_name: "$pros_cons.vendor_name",
      totalScore: {
        $reduce: {
          input: "$pros_cons.score",
          initialValue: 0,
          in: {
            $sum: [
              "$$value",
              "$$this.confident_score"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Sample Demo on Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ZgQVb_5zi2g)

Comment: it's working but not getting the details about the vendor

Comment: Hi, can I know what do you mean by details about the vendor? Would be suggested that you attach your expected output (Bson document) in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Please check the required.

Comment: Hi, checked your latest update on the question, my answer and demo fulfills your requirement,

Comment: is it possible to get the count of objects?

Comment: Hi, can you specify the count for which objects?

Comment: With`$size`. You may check out this [demo](https://mongoplayground.net/p/T5uz3HTxfZs).

Comment: count the numbers of object in score array

Comment: count:{$size: "$pros_cons.score"}, added this line after (_id: 0) in projection it worked :)